# How to get response body in NGRX effect if HTTP status code is 400

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I made an HTTP call to server and it returns HTTP status code 400 with response body as

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "businessErrorCode": "panelmaintenanceservice.failure.0",
    "message": ""
}
```

How can I get the error body in my NGRX effect. Here is the code sample

```
 savePanelEffect$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(savePanel),
        mergeMap(action => this.postPanelRequest(action).pipe(map(res => this.dispatchPanelSaved(res))))
    )
});

postPanelRequest(action: TypedAction<'[Product State] SavePanel'>) {
    this.store.dispatch(setPanelSavingState({ saving: LoadingState.Loading }));

    const payload = () => this.mapper.createPanelPayload(panel);
    const panelURL = `${this.apiBaseUrl}${environment.CREATE_SUBPANEL_API}`

    return this.http.post<any>(panelURL, payload).pipe(
        catchError(error => {
            console.log(error);
            return of(this.store.dispatch(fetchError()));
        })
    );
}

dispatchPanelSaved(response) {
    this.spinnerService.hide();

    if (!response) {
        this.store.dispatch(setPanelSavingState({ saving: LoadingState.Error }));
    }

    return setPanelSavingState({ saving: LoadingState.Done });
}
```

P.S: console.log(error) logs undefined.

Comment: So what do you get as a response? Is it a real 400 HTTP error, or is it HTTP 200 with response as we can see it. And what do you mean by getting response body in effect? Do you want to do something with it after the `mergeMap`?